# Ideas to improve website loading speed?

Tags: optimization, performance, page-speed

Are there any ways in which I can improve the loading speed of a website?

I know that Google is really pushing loading speeds and with the popularity of mobile websites it's now imperative that sites load quickly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. [Yahoo's tips for improving page sped](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
2. [Google's tips for improving page speed](https://web.dev/lighthouse-performance/)
3. If you're using PHP, [Google's tips for making PHP faster](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php.html)

Here's a basic list as comprised from [Google's Page Speed addon](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) (here's [Yahoo's YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)):

- Leverage browser caching
- Specify image dimensions
- Avoid CSS @import
- Avoid bad requests
- Combine images into CSS sprites
- Defer parsing of JavaScript
- Enable Keep-Alive
- Enable compression
- Inline Small CSS
- Inline Small JavaScript
- Make landing page redirects cacheable
- Minify CSS
- Minify HTML
- Minify JavaScript
- Minimize redirects
- Minimize request size
- Optimize images
- Optimize the order of styles and scripts
- Prefer asynchronous resources
- Put CSS in the document head
- Remove query strings from static resources
- Serve resources from a consistent URL
- Serve scaled images
- Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header
- Specify a cache validator
- Specify a character set
- Defer loading of JavaScript
- Remove unused CSS
- Use efficient CSS selectors

I strongly recommend using either Google's or Yahoo's page speed add-ons to test out your pages. It's fast and easy to do and offers clear guidance on how to improve your page speeds.

**update**

As recommended by Nick in the comments here are some more good resources and information:

- Steve Souder's [tips](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/rules.php) and [book](http://stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/23/even-faster-web-sites):
- [Facebook's go-to references when they first optimised their site](http://facebook.com/note.php?note_id=307069903919)

**update 2**

Here's come good stats that shows why page speed is important ([source](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/12/web-performance-optimization-is-the-new-seo/))

> - Amazon: 100 ms delay caused a [drop in revenue](http://glinden.blogspot.com/2006/11/marissa-mayer-at-web-20.html).
> - Google: 400 ms delay caused a [0.59% decrease in search requests per
>   user](http://velocityconf.com/velocity2009/public/schedule/detail/8523).
> - Yahoo!: 400 ms delay caused a [5-9% decrease in traffic](http://www.slideshare.net/stoyan/dont-make-me-wait-or-building-highperformance-web-applications).
> - Bing: 2 seconds delay caused a [4.3% drop in revenue per user](http://velocityconf.com/velocity2009/public/schedule/detail/8523).
> - Mozilla made their download page 2.2 seconds faster and was rewarded with
>   an increase of [15.4% in
>   downloads](http://blog.mozilla.com/metrics/category/website-optimization/).
> - Google Maps reduced the file volume by 30% and observed a [30% increase in
>   map requests](http://news.cnet.com/8301-10784_3-9954972-7.html).
> - Netflix, which uses Appdynamics to monitor their performance, enabled
>   gzip on the server; simply by this
>   single action pages became 13-25%
>   faster and [saved 50% of traffic
>   volume](http://velocityconf.com/velocity2008/public/schedule/detail/3632)!
> - Shopzilla succeeded in reducing the loading time from 7 down to 2 seconds,
>   whereby the [conversion rate increased
>   by 7-12%](http://velocityconf.com/velocity2009/public/schedule/detail/7709), they observed a 25%
>   increase in page requests, they were
>   able to [retire 50% of their
>   servers](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/06/how-green-is-your-web-page/), thus saving energy
>   costs.
> - AOL observed the [number of page views on several websites](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16878352/The-Secret-Weapons-of-the-AOL-Optimization-Team). While
>   the fastest users requested 7-8 pages,
>   the slowest only viewed 3-4.
> - Edmunds got down from over 10 seconds to less than 2, adding 17%
>   page views and [increasing revenue by
>   3%](http://technology.edmunds.com/blog/2010/11/how-edmunds-got-in-the-fast-lane.html).

Comment: +1 Also worth mentioning Steve Souder's tips here: http://stevesouders.com/hpws/rules.php and his book here: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/23/even-faster-web-sites/ These were Facebook's go-to references when they first optimised their site: https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=307069903919

Comment: I've got a feeling something in my header is making the site chugg along!

Comment: I am not sure that I like this answer as it does not really describe how to make a fast website, only what you can tinker with to get it faster. It is a bit like saying 'add a spoiler on a car' - which anyone can do - but you have to understand the general principles of aerodynamics for it to make sense and therefore to be done properly.

Comment: @Matthew, the Google and Yahoo add-ons and pages describe why these optimizations help. The informative as well as useful.

Comment: Just had a score of 89/100 for Google speed check, pretty good considering I haven't attempted any speed optimisations.

Answer (score 1):

Try CloudFlare http://www.cloudflare.com/plans

CloudFlare is a content delivery network and distributed domain name server service marketed as improving website performance and speed and providing security.