# SEO and other impacts of using rel="dns-prefetch"

Tags: seo, dns, rel-dns-prefetch

I recently came across a site that had the following code:

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//ajax.googleapis.com">
```

In [looking it up](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/PreResolveDns) it says it is used to `Reduce DNS lookup time by pre-resolving at the browser.`

So my question is, other than (hopefully) making the site feel a touch more faster, does it have any other impacts on SEO or the site in general?

Comment: I learned something new today. Thanks! As far as SEO, I am sure it is minimal in that it effects page speed- meaning that if page speeds are within the *okay* realm and under normal conditions any reference resolves *okay*, then the effect would be fairly small, but if there are resources in the HTML code that resolve slower and slows the page speed enough to effect this ranking metric, then the result would be much larger. So it would depend on the resources and the DNS (users or SOA) and how well they resolve. It could be a case by case thing. Other than that, I have no idea as to effect.

Comment: Nice question (and new tag!). I never thought of that in terms of SEO, but faster is always a plus for users and bots alike. Maybe someone will have some experience on their results with using it.

Comment: Often I see dns-prefetch implemented on commonly used URLs anyway, so I am not sure how much value it has in general in terms of page performance as these domains are likely already in your DNS cache.  If you had many unique DNS lookups required, I could see the utility.

Comment: Got a feeling it gives a better score on pagespeed, which is a good thing.

Comment: CSS Tricks has an [article on prefetching](https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/) and more that helps explain some of this. Worth reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google and other search engines ignore tags they don't recognize and directives that are not specifically geared towards search engines.  As such there will be no direct impact on rankings.  Search engines won't use dns-prefetch as a direct ranking signal.

There are indirect SEO benefits when your site is faster.  Google does measure how users react to your website.  Do they hit the back button because the site is too slow?    If using  dns-prefetch makes your site appear more quickly to users, then by all means use it.  See: [Why is loading speed of a website important for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42967/why-is-loading-speed-of-a-website-important-for-seo)