# How to add custom CSS for Addthis and validate on W3C validator?

Tags: css, javascript, addthis, w3c-validation

I have Addthis code on the very bottom of the page HTML code, and then, after it I have CSS file with some custom decorations of Addthis widget.

Everything looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js%23pubid=bigjohn;%23async=1"></script>
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/a.css" type="text/css">
</body></html>
```

The problem is that having CSS file in there hurts my W3C validation, as CSS file should be in the body of the HTML document, and W3C validator gives this error:
**Element link is missing required attribute property.**

Is there any chance of doing it the other way so W3C validation goes fine?

Comment: Is your CSS currently working OK with it located as above, but is simply failing validation?

Comment: @w3d Yes, everything works fine, I just want it to be valid.

Comment: In that case you probably need to look at _specificity_ (see my comment on bybe's answer below). As bybe says, your styles need to go in the HEAD section in order to pass validation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that CSS with `<link>` should be placed within `<head> </head>` and not within the tags `<body> </body>`. This should fix your validation problems.

e.g:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
    <link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="a.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>Example Header</h1>
            <span>Example of what a tagline looks like</span>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <p>This is dummy content of the article or page content.</p>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>Example of dummy footer content within article</p>
        </footer>
    </article>
<script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js%23pubid=bigjohn;%23async=1"></script>
</body>
```

CSS files have and always should be loaded in `<head>`. If you want to use styling outside of the head then you use inline styling which looks something like `<div style="background:#fff;"> </div>` and this does not support loading of files i.e CSS. If your worried about load times then you can extract the contents of the CSS file and place it into your site CSS so that way your not loading multiple files. See [John's Answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15380/ideas-to-improve-website-loading-speed/15381#15381) on [Ideas to improve website loading speed?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15380/ideas-to-improve-website-loading-speed) on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: unfortunately putting a CSS file within <head> </head> is not gonna work as CSS needs to go after the Addthis script, to override Addthis styles with my custom ones. I cannot use inline CSS as well since I have no way of getting inside of Addthis code and insert my inline style into it.

Comment: @CamSpy: The CSS does not necessarily need to be physically located after the script in order to override styles that the script might generate. You need to use [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). ie. Make your custom styles more "specific".

Comment: @w3d thanks for that, silly me I couldn't think of this myself, it perfectly solves the issue! However, since you did not post this as an answer, but comment only, I cannot select it as the solution. Post it as an answer so i will do my part

Comment: @CamSpy CSS generally works in reserve order in terms of importance. So the first is less important as the last... So if you have rules that clash the last CSS will be treated as more important as the first CSS file unless a `!important` Is used. Put `<link>` after all your other CSS files and it'll work fine. Or use more specific styling in your main template as @w3d has suggested, but correct loading of order of CSS will resolve this issue too.. if using WP check your enqueues and load via functions or similar rather than editing just the header.php.