# How to know if visitors are experiencing a good performance from the server?

Tags: performance

Sometimes I visit my wordpress website on godaddy, and looks like the site is slow. But when I refresh it goes fast.

I wonder how often this occur to my visitors on the month. Is there a way to know?

Comment: Sorry but there is already a handful of questions and answers on Pro Webmasters already regarding how to test your website speed. Your question about why its slow on the first and then fast on the refresh this is because of 'server first byte' which is waiting for your server to reply. You can test your site using a range of online speed testers to establish your slow server byte (shared hosting, especially GoDaddy is slow on first byte) You may also find [ideas to improve website loading speed](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15380/ideas-to-improve-website-loading-speed) useful.

Comment: @SimonHayter unfortunately pagespeed and the like are not a good indicator of actual user trends. Also, in addition to first byte it could be a caching daemon/mod/plugin generating (slow) on expired caches then fast (via fresh cache) on other tries later. You can use a server monitor + APM such as Newrelic for deep user interaction insights. Look for the "appdex" to see what percentage of users are happy/tolerating/unusable. Assimilate to load, traffic, cache stats/trends, etc, or further dig to understand if there are other bottlenecks going on that aren't apparent on the surface.

Comment: @SimonHayter I really want to know if, at any time, or when there are many users acessing the website, the server is still answering fine. If I measure at given moments I'll not have this information.

Comment: @dhaupin the user is asking how to test for visitors, I never implied that it was just about page speed. In regards of testing the performance of the server the question linked is relevant and I recommend that you leave what you've said in comment as an answer if your dissatisfied with the current answers. http://www.webpagetest.org/ is generally enough for most people wanting to test multiple threads with repeating tests, and even better emulation of real visitors is using their API. The user also using GoDaddy, likely shared which doesn't allow newrelic.

Comment: This has been closed as a duplicate of a question which has *very little to do with the question being asked here*. However as it stands its somewhat too broad to answer at all on this forum (it took me about 3 chapters in https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Colin_McKinnon_Linux_Apache_MySQL_PHP_Performance?id=Z3ciBgAAQBAJ&hl=en_GB )