# The time it takes to download a page from our website is increasing in Google Search Console, what should I do?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index

The time for pages on my site is really increasing, so the number of our pages getting indexed is decreasing. What should I do?

Comment: Presumably you haven't changed anything on your site that could influence the download time? Has your host?? What is _your_ measured download time - does this relate to Google's report?

Comment: @w3dk The OP should be checking the site and server for issues of course, however, I have noticed that G is reporting ridiculous download times that do not reflect reality. G has reported times consistently within the 7 second range when the site still loads within .5 seconds. For a period of months, the time would go up slowly and has now returned back to normal. All the while, nothing has changed and internal measures are normal including network throughput in the router. I am convinced that G has lost it's ever loving mind on download times. Good thing it is not a rank metric... ;-)

Comment: Yes it is webmaster report .. we change our cdn but we have checked it and its not for it :(

Comment: The indexed page count is separate from the download time (and probably not a problem). The time spent downloading is aggregated across all URLs fetched from the server, so if you have a bunch of large or slow URLs, they will pull the average down. When time spent downloading goes up, usually Google just crawls less, which is fine for most sites (unless you have millions of pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google allocates time spent on a website mostly based on your domains authority and how it important your content is considered. Domain authority is complex but considered to be based mostly on age, influence and quality.

If your site has become slower but your authority has remained the same then Google will not increase your allocated crawl time and will be able to crawl less within the given time.

*To increase your authority:*

- Focus on publishing even higher quality content.
- Try and get your content buzzing which will increase your SEO leads that in turn improves authority.
- Become the best in your niche.

*Improve the amount of pages crawled in one session*

- [Improve your site optimisation](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15380/ideas-to-improve-website-loading-speed/15381#15381) with various methods to decrease render and download time.
- Speed test your website using [Web Page Speed Test](https://www.webpagetest.org/), use multiple locations and passes.

  - 1 second = Good
  - 2 second = Ok
  - 3 second = Poor
  - 4 second = Bad

Comment: I have experienced the same thing as the OP, though I have no clue as to why. I monitor my sites in a multitude of ways and the site speed has not increased, however, Google Search Console is has increased from .44 seconds to over 7 seconds. Now it is going back down to normal. This is over a period of several months. GSC times do not reflect reality. My local measures are still in the sub-second ranges. I can also measure the time it takes to satisfy a request on the server, and the times jive with my local monitor. I checked my network router for load, and all is clear.

Comment: our site is a classified ads website and the content is generated b people and we haven't change it... I test the page with the site you have mentioned and its Good... so what is increasing for?

Comment: User generated content is generally bad because the users will often use duplicate text from other websites and sources... Because of this Google considers those pages less important and enough of those types of pages then it considers the site less important... because your not offering any else that people can't read else where.

Comment: Can you share the results of 'GOOD' please since it'll provide a URL with it.

Comment: Yes you can test https://divar.ir and its pages